# React - How to prevent re-rendering of all the input fields when input changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, redux

I am implementing a form which is generated using a Json. The Json is retrieved from API and then looping over the items I render the input elements. Here is the sample  Json :

```
{
  name: {
      elementType: 'input',
      label: 'Name',
      elementConfig: {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'Enter name'
      },
      value: '',
      validation: {
        required: true
      },
      valid: false,
      touched: false
    }
   }
```

Here is how I render the form :

```
    render() {
        const formElementsArray = [];
        for (const key in this.props.deviceConfig.sensorForm) {
         formElementsArray.push({
            id: key,
            config: this.props.deviceConfig.sensorForm[key]
         });

    const itemPerRow = 4;
      const rows = [
        ...Array(Math.ceil(props.formElementsArray.length / itemPerRow))
      ];
      const formElementRows = rows.map((row, idx) =>
        props.formElementsArray.slice(
          idx * itemPerRow,
          idx * itemPerRow + itemPerRow
        )
      );
      const content = formElementRows.map((row, idx) => (
        <div className='row' key={idx}>
          {row.map((formElement) => (
            <div className='col-md-3' key={formElement.id}>
              <Input
                key={formElement.id}
                elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
                elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
                value={formElement.config.value}
                invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
                shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
                touched={formElement.config.touched}
                label={formElement.config.label}
                handleChange={(event) => props.changed(event, formElement.id)}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
 ...
    }
```

I am storing the form state in redux and on every input change , I update the state. Now the problem is everytime I update the state, the entire form is re-rendered again... Is there any way to optimise it in such a way that only the form element which got updated is re-rendered ?

Edit :

1. I have used `React.memo` in `Input.js` as  :
   `export default React.memo(input);`
2. My stateful Component is Pure component.
3. The Parent is class component.

Edit 2 :

Here is how I create `formElementArray` :

```
const formElementsArray = [];
for (const key in this.props.deviceConfig.sensorForm) {
    formElementsArray.push({
    id: key,
    config: this.props.deviceConfig.sensorForm[key]
});
```

Comment: I don't see an id in in your json - is there one?

Comment: @WillJenkins the id is key name i.e `name` in the Json

Comment: how is name mapped to id? it isn't shown in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make content as a separate component like this.
And remove `formElementsArray` prop from parent component.

```
export default function Content() {
  const formElementRows = useForElementRows();
      formElementRows.map((row, idx) => (
            <Input
              formId={formElement.id}
              handleChange={props.changed}
            />
      )
}
```

Inside Input.js

```
const handleInputChange = useCallback((event) => {
   handleChange(event, formId);
}, [formId, handleChange]);
<input handleChange={handleInputChange} />
export default React.memo(Input)
```

So you can memoize `handleChange` effectively. And it will allow us to prevent other `<Input />` 's unnecessary renders.
By doing this forElementRows change will not cause any rerender for other components.

Comment: once Input changes , the form state is updated. Wouldn't this cause `Content` to re-render? and  as a result all `Input` re-renders ??

Comment: Only Content will rerender bcs it's state chagned, but not for other Inputs since their props didn't change.

Comment: And yes Input should be pureComponent. Which is needed to skip rerender when it's props didn't change. In general Input is purecomponent naturally.

Comment: I have updated answer since you need to memorize handlechange. If Input is not Purecomponent, you can just wrap it with React.memo(Input) on it's export

Comment: Main issue was handlechange, since it's created everytime we rerender Content.

Comment: I just updated my answer and it will allow us to effectively memorize handleChange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232745/discussion-between-programoholic-and-zhang-tianyu).

Answer (score 1):

You could try a container, as TianYu stated; you are passing a new reference as change handler and that causes not only the component to re create jsx but also causes virtual DOM compare to fail and React will re render all inputs.

You can create a container for Input that is a pure component:

```
const InputContainer = React.memo(function InputContainer({
  id,
  elementType,
  elementConfig,
  value,
  invalid,
  shouldValidate,
  touched,
  label,
  changed,
}) {
  //create handler only on mount or when changed or id changes
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    (event) => changed(event, id),
    [changed, id]
  );
  return (
    <Input
      elementType={elementType}
      elementConfig={elementConfig}
      value={value}
      invalid={invalid}
      shouldValidate={shouldValidate}
      touched={touched}
      label={label}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
});
```

Render your InputContainer components:

```
{row.map((formElement) => (
  <div className="col-md-3" key={formElement.id}>
    <InputContainer
      key={formElement.id}
      elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
      elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
      value={formElement.config.value}
      invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
      shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
      touched={formElement.config.touched}
      label={formElement.config.label}
      //re rendering depends on the parent if it re creates
      //  changed or not
      changed={props.changed}
    />
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Yeah.. I got the mistake  I did

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some steps to stop re-rendering. To do that we have to use `useMemo()` hook.

First Inside `Input.jsx` memoize this component like the following.

```
export default React.memo(Input);
```

Then inside `Content.jsx`, memoize the value of **`elementConfig`**, **`shouldValidate`**, **`handleChange`** props. Because values of these props are object type (non-primitive/reference type). That's why every time you are passing these props, they are not equal to the value previously passed to that prop even their value is the same (memory location different).

```
const elementConfig = useMemo(() => formElement.config.elementConfig, [formElement]);
const shouldValidate = useMemo(() => formElement.config.validation, [formElement]);
const handleChange = useCallback((event) => props.changed(event, formElement.id), [formElement]);

return <..>
  <Input
    elementConfig={elementConfig }
    shouldValidate={elementConfig}
    handleChange={handleChange}
  />
<../>
```

As per my knowledge, this should work. Let me know whether it helps or not. Thanks, brother.

Comment: Thanks, @gmoniava. Sorry for that mistake. Edited my answer.

Comment: how elementConfig will get `formElement` obbject ??

Comment: @programoholic Ahh... It's a problem. Outside the loop, it won't get this variable. Then you can try wrapping the full loop in useMemo.